# "Type'Program' does not conform to protocol 'Any Object'"

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, tableview

I updated xcode and now I have error in my project and I dont have idea what to do with it.

```
struct Program {
    let name : String
    let url : String
}

self.arrayOfPrograms = [Program(name: "First", url: "http://1.com"), Program(name: "Second", url: "http://2.com"), Program(name: "Third", url: "http://2.com")]
```

and I'm getting error "Type'Program' does not conform to protocol 'Any Object'"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As reported in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_516):

> AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type.

A struct is not a class, so it cannot be cast to `AnyObject`

You should either:

- turn `Program` into a class
- define your array as `Array<Any>`
- if your array is supposed to hold instances of `Program` only, declare it as `Array<Program>`

Needless to say, the last is the best solution, whereas the first is the one I wouldn't recommend because it requires you to make design changes (there's a reason why you declared it as a value type and not a reference type).

Side note: arrays and dictionaries can be cast to `AnyObject` because they are automatically bridged respectively to `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`, which are classes.

Answer (score 0):

> check this link you got your answare I recently wrapped my head around
>   something that I have found very strange in Swift. Swift provides two
>   high level protocols called Any and AnyObject. Any can be used for
>   both value types (like structs) and reference types (classes) while
>   AnyObject can only be used for classes.

[enter link description here](http://www.drewag.me/posts/swift-s-weird-handling-of-basic-value-types-and-anyobject)